# Is it possible to split a detached ruleset in less (into property + value)?

Tags: css, less

I am trying to make a less mixin that receives a detached ruleset. Is there a way to extract or split the detached ruleset into property + value?

```
@ruleset : {opacity:.5};
.myMixin(.4s, @ruleset);

.myMixin(@duration, @ruleset){
    @ruleset(); <-- looking to split this so I can zero out the property
}
```

I understand I am able to use some JS in less and I have even used Math.random() before. Maybe I can leverage something like split()?

Comment: No, as far as I know that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your ruleset as array:

```
@ruleset: opacity .5, color red;
```

So this `@ruleset` is two-dimensional array: `[[opacity, .5], [color, red]]`.

Then you can go through array and do what you want with key and value pairs.

```
@ruleset: opacity .5, color red;

.myMixin(
  @duration, 
  @array, 
  @iterator: 1
) when(@iterator <= length(@array)) {

  // Get key and value from array
  @name:  extract(extract(@array, @iterator), 1);
  @value: extract(extract(@array, @iterator), 2);

  // Here you have current @name, @value and @duration
  .property-@{iterator} {
    duration: @duration;
    name:     @name;
    value:    @value;
  }

  // Next iteration
  .myMixin(@duration, @array, @iterator + 1);
}
.myMixin(.4s, @ruleset);
```

This code will generate the following css:

```
.property-1 {
  duration: 0.4s;
  name: opacity;
  value: 0.5;
}
.property-2 {
  duration: 0.4s;
  name: color;
  value: red;
}
```

**IMO:**
I recommend you to avoid complex logic in less. It would be difficult to understand for the new team member how does this code work. And you will forget how this code works after a couple of weeks.
Styles must be as simple and clear as it can be.